# Select sql statement for Mysql

Tags: sql, select

I have this bit of sql

```
SELECT pd.id, pd.title, pd.fname, pd.lname, pd.DOB, pd.phone_home, pd.phone_biz, pd.phone_contact, pd.phone_cell, pd.sex, pd.email, pd.pid, f.form_id, ldf1.field_value AS autoleaxis, ldf2.field_value AS autolecyl
FROM patient_data pd
LEFT JOIN forms f ON pd.pid = f.pid
LEFT JOIN  `lbf_data` ldf1 ON ldf1.form_id = f.form_id
LEFT JOIN  `lbf_data` ldf2 ON ldf1.form_id = ldf2.form_id
WHERE (
f.form_name =  'Opthalmology'
AND ldf1.field_id =  'autoleaxis'
AND ldf2.field_id =  'autolecyl'
)
OR (
f.form_id IS NULL 
AND ldf1.field_id IS NULL 
AND ldf2.field_id IS NULL
)
ORDER BY pd.pid
```

Which is for a MySQL Database. It works ok except it is returning more than one record per person in some cases as they have more than one form_id. How do I restrict it so that it only returns the records for highest form_id that the person has or form_id set to null if there isn't one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subquery in `LEFT JOIN`, as with:

```
SELECT *
FROM patient_data pd
LEFT JOIN 
(
  select max(form_id) as form_id, pid, form_name
  from forms as f2
) as f
ON pd.pid = f.pid
LEFT JOIN  `lbf_data` ldf1 ON ldf1.form_id = f.form_id
LEFT JOIN  `lbf_data` ldf2 ON ldf1.form_id = ldf2.form_id
WHERE (
f.form_name =  'Opthalmology'
AND ldf1.field_id =  'autoleaxis'
AND ldf2.field_id =  'autolecyl'
)
OR (
f.form_id IS NULL 
AND ldf1.field_id IS NULL 
AND ldf2.field_id IS NULL
)
ORDER BY pd.pid
```

You can test in [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edd45/10)

Comment: Thanks I did wonder about subqueries but got so confused afterr trying different options